# How to force my Samsung monitor and nVidia card to display in 3D?

Tags: graphics-card, monitor, hardware, stereo-3d

I have a Samsung 27LSA950 monitor and apparently there is licencing issues between Samsung and nVidia with regards to 3D games.

I have Geforce 570 2.5Gb GPU.

There was previously a solution on how to workaround this on the nVidia forums, but has since been deleted by them to avoid legal problems related to their licensing issue.

Can anyone provide this workaround, or another solution on how I can use the nVidia 3D software through my Samsung monitor?

The only games I have managed to get it working on was Battlefield 3 and Skyrim, by reverting to older versions of the Driver. This was temporary though and not great quality. Any game with it's own inbulit 3D, such as Crysis 2 etc. Work fine. I think they may be running through the Tridef software in the monitor though. Not sure. But the usual functionality of nVidias 3D vision is now not working at all for any game. This has been going on for months, and at this stage, an answer would be amazing.

Comment: This seems a valid question to me—does the close-voter want to give their reasoning?

Comment: This is not a gaming specific question IMO (I didn't close vote it)

Comment: To weigh in here, the 3D software is only relating to 3D Games. All other 3D functionality works fine.

Comment: Which game doesn't activate the 3D?  Perhaps it doesn't have 3D?  Is it more than one game?  There might be a better reception if this was specific to a game, so we could figure out what's going on.

Comment: The only games I have managed to get it working on was Battlefield 3 and Skyrim, by reverting to older versions of the Driver. This was temporary though and not great quality. Any game with it's own inbulit 3D, such as Crysis 2 etc. Work fine. I think they may be running through the Tridef software in the monitor though. Not sure. But the usual functionality of nVidias 3D vision is now not working at all for any game. This has been going on for months, and at this stage, an answer would be amazing.

Comment: Sounds gaming-specific with those details. Stick that in the question.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for, but I can't try it, so it gets a comment: http://3dvision-blog.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2025